# Rename multiple files according using a names-list

Tags: rename, batch-jobs

I'm trying to rename multiple numbered files according to a list of names.

Example:

```
1.pdf, 2.pdf, …, n.pdf
```

And a file called `names.txt`, with a value per line:

```
Fabio
Joao
n-name
```

So we will have

- `1.pdf` → `Fabio.pdf`
- `2.pdf` → `Joao.pdf`
- `n.pdf` → `n-name.pdf`

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @FabioB,  We had a exact identical question over at AskUbuntu!  :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281686/renaming-multiple-files-corresponding-to-a-list-in-file/1281690#1281690

Comment: How do you determine the matching? Will the first row of `names.txt` go to the first, sorting alphabetically ascending, existing filename? Or you have another file `old_names.txt` that matches one to one the new `names.txt`?

Comment: No @roaima, it's a routine I'm trying to accomplish to avoid repetitive tasks at work.

Comment: @thanasisp It will be the first row with the first sorted number. I will scan many documents in a certain order and name then from 1.pdf to n.pdf and after renaming them from the list. It's an employee list.

Comment: @steeldriver I answerd with a post I did on AskUbuntu; But thanks that's some good insight too; //Best Wishes

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates of this right here, please try to suggest dupes that are on _this_ site and can be used as dupe targets.

Comment: Fabio, how can we get the list of target files. Can we assume it will be `*.pdf`? Or will it be `{1..N}.pdf`? Or perhaps `[0-9]*pdf`? Something else? Will you have two lists, one with the original file name and one with the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are really just "lineNumber.pdf", then this is very easy to do. In the shell:

```
c=0
while IFS= read -r name; do
    ((c++))
    echo mv -- $c.pdf "$name.pdf"
done < names.txt
```

Once you're sure that works as you want it, remove the `echo` from the `mv` command.

If you have very many files, you might want to consider doing it in Perl instead which will be much faster:

```
perl -lne 'rename("$..pdf","$_.pdf")' names.txt
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot.